# Application is not serving the request when connection pool reaches to maximum number of connections

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, hikaricp

I seen a strange issue while doing stress testing. Following is my spring configuration.

```
spring:   
  datasource:
    communicationtimeout: 60000
    jpa:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 30000
      idle-timeout: 600000
      max-lifetime: 1800000
      maximum-pool-size: 25
      minimum-idle: 3
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    database-platform:  org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

When the number of db connections reach to 25 (maximum-pool-size: 25), I observed that the request going to this VM are not serving and went to infinite loop. I do not see any error in the logs. I would like to know how to find the root cause or what is causing this issue?

**NOTE**
After we stopped the stress test too, this VM is not serving the new requests.

Spring boot version: 2.0.3.RELEASE

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Make sure you aren't messing around with connections yourself, second disable open in view `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` (although that might break your application on other ways if you rely on this).

Comment: Get a thread dump to show what the threads are waiting on. Chances are they are waiting on getting a connection from the pool, and you may have a connection leak if your other processes pull them but don't release them back.

Comment: I am using EntityManager for retrieval operaitons on non \@Transactional methods. is it causing any trouble?
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;